# some styles not being applied react-native

Tags: react-native

viewStyle not get appied. What am i doing wrong? 
I am going with a course and i write line by line but mine just gets applied textStyle.

i will be thankful for any idea

```js
const Header = (props) => {

    const { viewStyle, textStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 60,
        paddingTop: 15,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        elevation: 0.2,
        position: 'relative'    
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 20
    }

}
export default Header;
```

Comment: `<View style={styles.viewStyle}>`, in your code you're not accessing `styles` object

Comment: i have destructured it here : const { viewStyle, textStyle } = styles;

Comment: You're right, I should have been more careful. Btw it is a good practice to use [stylesheet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet) to define style objects and then access them directly as I did. That's why I've been baited to immediately answer you without paying the correct attention.

Comment: i tried stylesheet and then accessed them directly, but no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  import {StyleSheet,View,Text} from 'react-native'; 





  const Header = (props) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        viewStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: 60,
            paddingTop: 15,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
            shadowOpacity: 0.2,
            elevation: 0.2,
            position: 'relative'    
        },
        textStyle: {
            fontSize: 20
        }
    })
```

Comment: i was using an extra curly brace, i used stylesheet but still no change

Comment: ups, a extra curly brace slipped out, try it now . You should be using the component like so `<Component headerText='Hello' />`